# pandas: create column with string value based on conditions in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

In a dataframe I want to compute an additional column "desired_output" (default of "desired column" is 123456) that combines the values from another 6 columns (c_flow 1,c_flow 2,c_flow 3,c_flow 4,c_flow 5,c_flow 6)  as follows: if in a row in column 1=0.0 and column 4=0.0 then the "desired_output" becomes: x23x56.

"try1" is what I can output at the moment.

```
c_flow_1 = [1, 20, 0, 3, 0, 2]
c_flow_2 = [10, 20, 5, 10, 0, 0]
c_flow_3 = [10, 20, 0, 10, 1, 2]
c_flow_4 = [0, 20, 0, 10, 1, 2]
c_flow_5 = [10, 0, 1, 10, 1, 5]
c_flow_6 = [10, 0, 0, 10, 1, 2]
desired_output = ['123x56', '1234xx', 'x2xx5x', '123456','xx3456','1x3456']
data = pd.DataFrame({'c_flow 1': c_flow_1, 
                     'c_flow 2': c_flow_2, 
                     'c_flow 3': c_flow_3, 
                     'c_flow 4': c_flow_4,
                     'c_flow 5': c_flow_5, 
                     'c_flow 6': c_flow_6,
                     'desired_output': desired_output 
                    })

conditions = [data['c_flow 1'] == 0, data['c_flow 2'] == 0, data['c_flow 3'] == 0, 
              data['c_flow 4'] == 0, data['c_flow 5'] == 0, data['c_flow 6'] == 0 ]
choices = ['x23456', '1x3456', '12x456', '123x56', '1234x6', '12345x']
data['try1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default ='123456')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a little math to make things easier.

1. Filter out the columns you want. I use `DataFrame.filter` to do this
2. Get a mask of cells > 0
3. Multiply each row of this mask with a range (you want 1-6) using `DataFrame.mul`
4. Replace 0s in the result with `x` using `DataFrame.replace`
5. Aggregate the rows to form a single string, using `DataFrame.agg`

```
(data.filter(like='c_flow')   
     .gt(0)                   
     .mul(range(1, 7))        
     .replace(0, 'x')         
     .astype(str)             
     .agg(''.join, 1)         
)

0    123x56
1    1234xx
2    x2xx5x
3    123456
4    xx3456
5    1x3456
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank a lot, I was looking into it.  For me the agg part doesnt't work yet: I receive an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'. It work partwise without agg.

Comment: @Silvia You will need to upgrade your version of pandas for `agg` to work. For now, use `apply(''.join, 1)`,

Comment: I copy/paste the code and changed agg to apply, it works : but the solutions becomes 111x11, 2222xx etc.

Comment: @Silvia You forgot the `axis=1`... I specified it before but I'll repeat: `apply(''.join, axis=1)`

Comment: (data.filter(like='c_flow')   
     .gt(0)                   
     .mul(range(1, 7))        
     .replace(0, 'x')         
     .astype(str)             
     .apply(''.join, axis=1)        
) I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Silvia I added the comments so it was easy to understand, but the comments are not supposed to be added. I removed them so please try it again. It should work, let me know if it doesn't. :(

Comment: I am sorry I was just copy/pasting. My output is still 111x11. The comments were commented, so I dont have any error, it just the output is not the same as yours. It seems in my case the mul is done rowwise not  columnwise.

Comment: @Silvia please just update to the latest version of pandas, because this works for me on it. Bugs on older versions shouldn't be my headache to deal with ;)

Comment: Fare enough. Thank you for your input. I will try this from home, as of ourse I cannt update it here.

Comment: (data.filter(like='c_flow')   
     .gt(0)                   
     .mul([1,2,3,4,5,6], axis = 1)        
     .replace(0, 'x')         
     .astype(str).apply(''.join, axis = 'columns')                   
) - for pandas 0.19.2

Answer (score 1):

I tried this (I knew this is not effective), but still posting to get an idea

```
def cust(row):
    t=[]
    i=1
    for val in row:
        if val!=0:
            t.append(str(i))
        else:
            t.append('x')
        i+=1
    return ''.join(t)
print df.apply(cust,axis=1)
```